# Simple REST URL scheme

Tags: rest, restful-url

In my web app I've got a `user` model and a `journal` and `post` model. Each user can have multiple journals, each journal can have multiple posts. Is below the best way to represent this in a RESTful way?

```
/profiles/<username>
/profiles/<username>/journals/<journal_id>
/profiles/<username>/journals/<journal_id>/posts/<post_id>
```

or would:

```
/profiles/<username>
/journals/<journal_id>
```

be a better way to go?

Comment: You may find [this link](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/2/5/nesting-resources) useful. It's a bit old, but still very relevant (the official rails guides have it as a recommended resource too).

Comment: thanks for the link, just finished reading it. So a flatter hierarchy is considered the rule of thumb unless there are other factors to consider?

Comment: I'd design it so the user has to choose a url slug for each journal. Fewer numeric ids in the URL the better imo. Some systems even try to eliminate the post_id by converting the post subject into a sort of makeshift url slug. I'm not convinced that isn't overkill.

Comment: @JC. thanks will definitely use slugged post/journal titles in the URL now you mention it

Answer (score 0):

You have three types of resources: Profiles, Journals, and Posts.

If your business needs is to allow end-users to have access to them all, you will need to provide PUT/POST/GET/DELETE [CRUD operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) on these resources base on your needs (you may not need all operations on all resources thought)

```
/profiles/<username>/
/journals/<journal_id>/
/posts/<post_id>/
```

If you need to provide a logical mapping and relationship between these resources, you will also need to provide the following:

```
/profiles/<username>/journals/<journal_id>
/profiles/<username>/journals/<journal_id>/posts/<post_id>
```

You can also look into this [posting as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072693/a-restful-service-api-designing-issue/18158192#18158192)  what may be the approach to think about business relationship mapping between resources.