# HasMany RESTfull (or anti-RESTfull) Design?

Tags: rest, url, architecture

So I've been reading a lot on RESTfull design - specifically dealing with resources.

Taking the canonical example of **Users**, **Posts**, and **Comments**, with relationships as:

> Users ---(hasMany)---> Post ---(hasMany)---> Comment

One may initially think to expose something like:

```
GET /users               GET /posts               GET /comments 
POST /users              POST /posts              POST /comments 
GET /users/id            GET /posts/id            GET /comments/id
PUT /users/id            PUT /posts/id            PUT /comments/id
DELETE /users/id         DELETE /posts/id         DELETE /comments/id
```

But then, say I want all *Comments* of a certain *Post* made by a particular *User*. I'd need to do something like:

```
GET /users/id
   > someUser
   > var postIds = someUser.posts()
GET /posts?id=<postIds[0]>&id=<postIds[1]>&...
   > somePosts
   >  **application user inspects posts to see which one they care about**
   > var postOfInterest = somePosts[x]; 
   > var postId = postOfInterest.id;
GET /comments?id=postId
   > someComments (finally)
```

Suppose though I only care about a *Post* or *Comment* in the context of it's owner. Suppose a different resource structuring which may (or may not?) be more natural:

```
GET /users
POST /users  
GET /users/id   
PUT /users/id
DELETE /users/id

GET /users/id/posts
POST /users/id/posts
GET /users/id/posts/id
PUT /users/id/posts/id
DELETE /users/id/posts/id

GET /users/id/posts/id/comments
POST /users/id/posts/id/comments
GET /users/id/posts/id/comments/id
GET /users/id/posts/id/comments/id
GET /users/id/posts/id/comments/id
```

Which to me, is probably a better representation of what the resources are. Then all I need is:

```
GET /users/id/posts
   > somePosts
   > **application user inspects posts to see which one they care about**
   > var postOfInterest = somePosts[x];
   > var postId = postOfInterest.id;
GET /users/id/posts/postId/comments
   > someComments
```

This just seems more like navigating a file system than the previous method - but I don't know if its RESTfull at all (perhaps this is what REST was trying to *get rid of*) because in order to access a *Comments* resource, I need to know which *User* and which *Post* it belongs to. But the former requires 3 requests, while the latter requires just 2.

Thoughts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should I deal with object hierarchies in a RESTful API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867344/how-should-i-deal-with-object-hierarchies-in-a-restful-api)

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19033462/simple-rest-url-scheme.  See if it helps.  similar question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a bit of what is good REST is opinion but I would say your second approach is generally more "RESTful".

Basically you do want hierarchy in REST API and filesystem like navigation instead of query parameters. This is especially so if you follow HATEOS like API as someone can navigate your API.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was generally thinking. Would it be totally evil do go with the latter approach in general, but expose *convenience* routes like direct `/posts` when I only care about the data in a *Post* and not the context of who owns it?

Answer (score 1):

In your second example it's important to have *both* `GET /users/id` and `GET /users/id/posts` so that when a request for the user's info is made it doesn't include all it's posts (or their IDs) too. And the second request will return their posts too. Often users have thousands of posts in a forum.

The disadvantage is that the api user always has to know the author of the post for which it wants to get comments. He'd essentially make a "give me that user and give me his/hers posts" request to your server which means that your server will make a query for that user and then select his posts. Instead it's much more convenient for both your user and your server to have separate requests - "give me that user", "give me that post" and "give me that comment". This means that you have to store separately users, posts and comments and for each post/comment store the id of it's author so that you can make selection of posts/comments by their author ("give me posts by this user", or simply "give me this post")

I would personally go with this variant of requests

```
GET user
GET post
GET comment
...
```

For every request I'd implement a `where` clause which will give the user of my api more options to make a specific selection. For example `GET posts where userId='myID'`. It can be implemented with [url query parameters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) like `http://myapi.mydomain.com/post?userId=user1` or inside the header. It will return a list of posts for that user. You can also have `where` clause for the post's ID - `http://myapi.mydomain.com/post?id=123` which will return only this post. Note that for the first case - when you fetch a list of posts - you can only return some kind of short info for the posts (like id, author, summary...) and require an additional request to `post?id=id` for the full post content.

Having this implementation would give you at least two advantages:

- the user of the api needs to know only one id to get some info - postID to get a post's content/comments, userId to get all posts/comments for that user
- the selection is done on the server so less data is transfered over the network meaning faster responses (and potentially less costs for final users if they are on a mobile plan or something)

In my opinion this implementation giveс you loosely coupled objects (user, post, comment) and more flexible queries

Comment: Yes, this is the alternative. I fully agree that this gives me loosely coupled objects with more flexible queries - no argument there. But what if my resources are necessarily coupled, with strict *ownership* ? In my case, the hierarchy is 'walked' as users search for the leaf nodes in the hierarchy - with data loaded lazily. That is, if I'm doing a request for a resource at depth N, then there would necessarily have to have been requests for resource owners at depths N-1, N-2,..., 1

Comment: The thing is REST is not OOP. Its more like regular web pages with lots and lots of different views. That is a `comment` under the context of a `post` (`/post/{pid}/comment/{cid}`) is different than (`/comment/{cid}`). So while I appreciate @stan0 answer for the sake DRYness its more RPC than RESTful (IMHO).